# Why there are still so many opinion based questions? Should they be closed?

Tags: discussion, closing, close-reasons, soft-question

One of the reasons that we delete questions at math.stackexchange is because the answer is primarily opinion based. However, my observation is that there are still many such questions; they are not only never closed; instead, they are usually highly rated.

Here are a list of few examples:

1. [List of interesting math podcasts?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3/list-of-interesting-math-podcasts) (Interestingly, the question [List of Interesting Math Blogs](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/81/list-of-interesting-math-blogs) is closed though I failed to notice any substantial difference between the two.)
2. [What is your favorite online graphing tool?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/6/what-is-your-favorite-online-graphing-tool) (Is not the answer to one's favourite questions "opinion based"?)
3. [Where to go after calculus?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4862/where-to-go-after-calculus)
4. [Your favourite maths puzzles](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/566/your-favourite-maths-puzzles)
5. [Good books and lecture notes about category theory.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/370/good-books-and-lecture-notes-about-category-theory)
6. [List of interesting math videos / documentaries](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/18843/list-of-interesting-math-videos-documentaries)
7. [Math Major: How to read textbooks in better style or method ? And how to select best books?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/35105/math-major-how-to-read-textbooks-in-better-style-or-method-and-how-to-select)

I believe that there are much more such examples that are difficult for me to exhaust. My question is: do we allow such questions, or should we close all of them (or some of them) as they are opinion based?

Comment: The majority of these questions are *old*.

Comment: @AsafKaragila, being old means that they have very long lives. Will they live for ever?

Comment: The mission of Math.SE is to collect and *curate* excellent content for learners of mathematics at all levels.  There is an "old" post by Robert Cartaino (2010) which gives guidance about what informs deciding to close as "primarily opinion-based" (and this post was pointed out to you in a response to one of your recent related Questions).  If you feel that some specific post is not worth retaining at Math.SE, it would be more productive to flag that post than to ask yet another broad brush Question.